# Beginner Javascript problem .... iterating over array

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a task which i am trying to solve.

I have been set a task which most do the following;

1) On each number within the array, print out to screen (in an unordered list) each number’s array value and their associated description.

And the code is to do this task with is as follows;

```
var numbers = [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5',
  '6'
],

description = {
  'One': 'Number one',
  'Two': 'Number two',
  'Three': 'Number three',
  'Four': 'Number four',
  'Five': 'Number five',
  'Six': 'Number six'
};
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this using some sort of loop?

If you could also explain to me in comments to tell me whats happening that would be great.

Kind Regards,

B

Comment: Do you mean getting `Three` from `3`?

Comment: No what i mean is being able to print results on the screen like so; '1 Number one'

Comment: Then the specs make little sense. Object properties are not sorted so there is no reliable way to link e.g. the array item with index 2 (which happens to be "3") with the object property "Three". Their only actual link is that "three" is the English word for number three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign an array of objects, each object containing a description that corresponds to the index value of that object:

```
// assign an array of objects
// numbers[3] for example contains {name: 'Three', description: 'Number three'}
var numbers = [
  {name: 'Zero',  description: 'Zip!'},
  {name: 'One',   description: 'Number one'},
  {name: 'Two',   description: 'Number two'},
  {name: 'Three', description: 'Number three'},
  {name: 'Four',  description: 'Number four'},
  {name: 'Five',  description: 'Number five'},
  {name: 'Six',   description: 'Number six'}
],
// a results container
result = [];
// iterate through the numbers array and push a string
// string containing index, name and description to
// result
for (var i=0;i<numbers.length,i=i+1){
   result.push(i+': name = '+numbers[i].name+
               ', description = '+numbers[i].description);
}
// show the result, joining the result array into a string,
// separated by a line break '\n'
alert(result.join('\n'));

/* alerts:
 0: name = Zero, description = Zip!
 1: name = One, description = Number one
 2: name = Two, description = Number two
 3: name = Three, description = Number three
 4: name = Four, description = Number four
 5: name = Five, description = Number five
 6: name = Six, description = Number six
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var prop in description) {

    alert(prop+"::"+description[prop]);
}
```

This will help you iterate over your description object. You can modify it to match array values.

Comment: It's worth noting that `for(var ... in)` loops can be pretty counter-intuitive. See the explanation for **for statement** at http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: @ Álvaro G. Vicario ok i read the link but what's wrong with use of for in the context.

Comment: I'm not claiming it's right or wrong. I'm just stating that its behaviour is not always what intuition suggests (and I would not recommend it for arrays in any case).